# Confusion in the tensor product homomorphism in representations

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field and $G$ a group. Let $V$ and $W$ be two representations. And $V \otimes _k W$ be their tensor product which itself a representation with $G$ act on $V \otimes _k W$ by $g ( v \otimes w) = gv \otimes gw$.

I'm trying to prove Tensor-hom adjunction in the representation fashion. But I get stuck on one point, that is if $f: V \otimes _k W \to X$ is a $G$-homomorphism, fix $w \in W$. Then the $k-linear$ transformation $f_w: V \to X$ given by $f_w (v) = f (v \otimes w )$ is no longer a $G$-homomorphism since $f_w (gv) = f( gv \otimes w)$ while $ g f_w(v) = g f(v \otimes w ) = f ( g v \otimes gw)$?

I was confused on this point for a long time, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tensor-hom adjunction for $G$-representations takes the form

$$\text{Hom}(U \otimes V, W) \cong \text{Hom}(U, [V, W])$$

where I am using $[V, W]$ for the internal hom. This is the $k$-vector space of *all* homomorphisms $V \to W$, not just those respecting the action of $G$, with a suitable action of $G$. Among these, we can find the $G$-homomorphisms by looking at the $G$-fixed points. This corresponds to taking $U$ to be the trivial representation above, which gives

$$\text{Hom}(V, W) \cong \text{Hom}(1, [V, W]) \cong [V, W]^G.$$

In general, elements of $U$ don't give $G$-homomorphisms $V \to W$; it's morphisms $1 \to U$ which give $G$-homomorphisms, which correspond to $G$-invariant elements of $U$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean that the tensor-hom adjunction for $G$-representations (your first formula) only holds when $U$ is the trivial representation?

Comment: @user112564: it holds for all representations, but the point is that it does not follow that, given a morphism $f : U \otimes V \to W$, every element of $U$ gives a morphism $V \to W$. As you note in your question, this just isn't true. What does follow is that every morphism $1 \to U$ gives a morphism $V \to W$, and these correspond to the $G$-invariant elements of $U$.

Comment: Oh, I think I kind of get it now. But if only those $G$-invariant elements of $U$ give $G$-homomorphisms, how could the two hom-sets be bijection?

Comment: @user112564: work it out for yourself. One way of saying it is that both sides of the tensor-hom adjunction correspond to the $G$-invariants of $[U \otimes V, W] \cong [U, [V, W]]$; in other words, there is an *internal* tensor-hom adjunction which only mentions internal homs, and you get the ordinary tensor-hom adjunction by taking $G$-invariants.

Comment: Ok. So it seems more complicated than I thought. I already showed that any $G$-homomorphism from $U$ to $[V,W]$ actually gives a homomorphism from $U \otimes V$ to $W$, right? So the other direction is harder... And what is an internal hom?

Comment: @user112564: in this case, it's $[V, W]$. The other direction is just as easy. Spelling out my suggestion above in more words, show that the space of bilinear maps $U \times V \to W$ has a natural $G$-action on it and that the $G$-invariants of this $G$-action are simultaneously the $G$-maps $U \to [V, W]$ and also the $G$-maps $U \otimes V \to W$. In other words you are using the fact that you already know the tensor-hom adjunction for vector spaces (presumably) and the only additional thing to check is that the natural $G$-actions on everything match up.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. But it seems I misunderstood some of your words. In your notation $[V,W]$ and $Hom(V,W)$ all mean $G$-homomorphisms between $V$ and $W$?

Comment: @user112564: no. $[V, W]$ means the $k$-vector space of all $k$-linear maps $V \to W$ as a $G$-representation. This is the correct right adjoint to the tensor product. The $G$-action on $[V, W]$ is given by $f(v) \mapsto g f (g^{-1} v)$, and in particular it has the property that the $G$-invariant elements of $[V, W]$ are the $G$-homomorphisms $V \to W$.

Comment: Oh my god. I thought they need to be $G$-homomorphisms. I checked again and it only need to be $k$-linear transformations. That means what I've been doing are all correct. Damn! But anyway, thank you so much for going it through with me.